# Update facebook users profile informations via Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins, spring-social-facebook, facebook4j

I've created test users in my fb app and I need to personilize their profiles adding work positions, city, phone number, addresses and other informations.

Is it possible to do that programmatically?

Cause I've tested some Java API (**[Spring Social](https://projects.spring.io/spring-social/)** and **[facebook4j](http://facebook4j.github.io/en/index.html)**) but seems that I can only post messages, photo, video and  few other things.

I've also try to use the **Graph API Explorer** but  with same effects.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post code to which people can refer. Otherwise your question is too broad.

Comment: I'm not asking on specific code, I just want to know if there is a way to edit programmatically users profile info.

Comment: If you want them to have a user profile in your app, then you need to implement it yourself. As for their Facebook user profile, they have to maintain that themselves, via the Facebook UI, 3rd-party apps can't update that.